# Have issue with IE bug - CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I borrowed Css Globe's easy slider, but I modified it to be laid out on the page.

```
 /* numeric controls */ 



ol#controls{
  margin:0.2em 1em;
  padding:0;
  height:16px;
  float:right;
  font-size:x-small;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, Default;
  font-weight:normal;
 }

 ol#controls li{

  padding:0;
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
  height:16px;
  width:20px;
  background:yellow;
  margin:10px;
 }

 ol#controls li a{
  height:16px;
  line-height:18px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background:#FFFFFF;
  color:#555;
  padding:0 5px;
  text-decoration:none;
  float:right;
 }

 ol#controls li.current a{
  background:#736357;
  color:#fff;
 }
 ol#controls li a:focus, #prevBtn a:focus, #nextBtn a:focus{outline:none;}
```

I couldn't figure it out - IE7/8 slideshow navi (1,2,3,4) is spread widely when they should be arranged in close order to each other. See the example where they are spread widely. 
[image]

Any idea why it is behaving weirdly? Thank you!

Comment: can you provide the sample link to understand your problem properly

Comment: Margin & Padding CSS properties in IE. IE counts margin double than specified. http://article-stack.com/education/web-design-n-development/blog-blogger-blogging/css-ie-margin-fix.amty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing in IE8.

You have this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Which makes IE8 behave as if it's IE7 - that's not great, but it's not *the problem*.

You have this CSS file being included *only* if it's IE7 (which it "is" because of the above):

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/homepage_css/hpie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

On ~Line 75 of `hpie7.css`, you have this:

```
ol#controls li{
    margin:10px 100px 0 0; 
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    height:16px;
    line-height:18px; 
}
```

If you remove the `margin` line, the numbers will be close together again instead of `100px` apart.

It looks like you will have to (in the same file, so it's just for IE7) add a width to the `<ol>` like this:

```
ol#controls{
    ..
    width: 100px
}
```

Comment: Ok duh me and I forgot about hpie7.css and I deleted hpie8 since it is emulated in IE7 only. Thank you @thirtydot. One more thing, I am struggling with z-index for popup (newsletter signup) and it is still underneath the navigation and its dropdown. I googled and found out that relative + zindex gives IE bug but I added in z-index and they either go under or top of each other. Right now it isn't added in the hpie7.css yet. I am not sure why it's not working.